# cannot compile using g++ 4.2.2 with -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, g++, c++-concepts

I used features in c++0x, when I compile it with g++ 4.7.2. everything works fine. but I have a restriction to use g++ 4.2.2 to compile and it all started failing. is there a quick remedy that I can use so that my "so"s get compiled.

Comment: An error log would be nice.

Comment: cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"

Comment: constructor = delete;
typedef size_t size_type;
static const size_type npos = ~size_type(0);

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

That compiler is way too old, gcc started adding features in [4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).